# Scala Future does not return anything when allocating too much memory

Tags: scala, concurrent.futures

Using Scala-IDE 3.0.3 (based on Scala 2.10.4), the following code completes correctly by displaying the first 10 values of the computed `List` from a future as well as the `Future completed`message:

```scala
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object FutureNonBlocking extends App {

    val f1: Future[List[Int]] = future {
        val t = List.range(1, 50).filter(_ % 2 == 0)
        println("Done")
        t
    }

    f1.onComplete {
        case Success(value) => println(value.take(10))
        case Failure(e) => println("Something bad happened")
    }

    Await.complete(f1, 30 seconds)
}
```

However, changing the range `List.range(1, 50)` to `List.range(1, 5000)` does not display anything and (the `Failure` is not triggered). Logically, it seems to be related to a memory issue but I don't understand what is happening there.

Even stranger, running this code in a REPL does not cause the issue. What am I missing there?

Comment: I try this in repl, and found everything ok.

Comment: Seems to be working in my 2.10.3 REPL as well. The problem was seen in Scala-IDE 3.0.3-20140327, which is using Scala 2.10.4. Which version of Scala were you using?

Comment: I tried in a 2.10.4 REPL and this also works as expected. This seems then tied to Scala-IDE itself but I can't imagine why. Editing question accordingly.

Comment: If the app already stopped after run. Then I guess the console output is lost. Eclipse sometimes seems cannot display all console output in multi threading env. You try print that to a file and see the result.

Comment: This is it! Just adding a `Thread.sleep(1000)` to wait a bit solved the case. Thank you very much, I was afraid something odd was happening behind the scenes!

Comment: This is particularly a problem for the Eclipse Scala Worksheet - concurrent code often needs a sleep() at the end to keep the process alive long enough to see the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the whole thing is not an issue with memory management in `Futures` but it is related to the way Eclipse handles console output for concurrent programs.

Adding `Thread.sleep(1000)` at the end of the program let Eclipse show all the console output, solving the problem.

Thank you very much @jilen for your very helpful comment!

Comment: Await.ready(f1) only wait for f1 to complete, things in `f1.onComplete` may not executed yet. If you use the `transform` to create a new future and await for that future, things will be ok

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, this was a mistake. I have changed the original question to reflect this.